# FTP Write to file with QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, ftp

I search all over the internet and didn't find much. Here is my current code:

```
QNetworkAccessManager* qnam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QUrl url = QUrl("ftp://example.com/file.txt");
url.setHost(QString("ftp://example.com"));
url.setUserName(QString("user"));
url.setPassword(QString("pass"));
url.setPort(21);
QNetworkRequest req(url);
file.close();
```

From what I have now, how can I write to "file.txt" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (may be there could be other ways)

- You have to down load the file from FTP into a local file or stream.
- Then update the local file or stream.
- Upload the updated file or stream back to the FTP

**Gave an example using local file. Try by your self for stream if you want. The code is rough pseudo code. careful when you use it for production.**

First create a slot for `finished` signal of your network manager to completely read the file.

```
connect(qnam,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

Get the network reply as shown below.

```
QNetworkReply *nReply = qnam->get(req);
```

Create a slot function to read the complete file to your local.

```
void YourClass::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *data) {
    QFile file("YourFileName");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        return;
    file.write(data->readAll());
    file.close();
}
```

**Modify the local file as you want programatically.**

**Now upload the file back to FTP as said below.**

```
QNetworkRequest upload(url); 
qnam->put(upload, "YourFileName");
```

Comment: From your example, what is nReply for ? It's not used anywhere else... And to modify the file, does it create a copy locally ? If so, where is it ? And do I just modify it with basic c++ ?

Comment: QNetworkReply *nReply = qnam->get(req); After this statement execution only the slot replyFinished is called by Qt framework

Comment: Yes. Modify the local file with basic C++ or any library if you use

Comment: Hey, I tried what you told me and it didn't change the file when I tried it. It gave some errors.... The code: https://pastebin.com/Yq6HJta7 and errors: https://pastebin.com/GBye4DAA

Comment: Move connect statement immediately after qnam object is created. And do not modify the file inside "reply finished". Modify the file after QNetworkReply *nReply = qnam->get(req);

Comment: Nevermind, for some reasons, it gives the errors only some times. Last line is gone but all SSL sockets are still there... And this "QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply*, mail, pass)"

Comment: It is... I wonder if i should use this "ftp://whatever.com/file.txt" as the url or just "ftp://whatever.com" and it will figure out that the file is there... Anyway I'll check that tomorrow...

Comment: You should use "whatever.com/file.txt".